# Pandas Data Frame Column structure

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am looking for a simple and elegant way to create the Pandas DataFrame similar to the Excel Table. The example is given below.

```
Name  |  Completed  | Not Completed|
      |   M  |  F   |   M   |   F  |
A     |   1  |  2   |   1   |   2  |
B     |   2  |  5   |   5   |   7  |
```

Sorry I am unable to show it properly and if some one revise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make two DataFrames and concatenate them.

```
df = pd.concat([DataFrame({'M': [1, 2], 'F': [2, 5]}), \
                DataFrame({'M': [1, 5], 'F': [2, 7]})], \
                axis=1, keys=['Completed', 'Not Completed'])

df.index = ['A', 'B']

df.index.name = 'Name'
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. That does it perfectly.